# Problem with kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I hope you can help me.I have a problem with kinect. I open a terminal and write "roscore" then I open a new terminal for lunch my kinect. I open a new terminal for a make and after I open a new terminal for run my ros node. The first time I always get my results, but if I want to repeat the acquisition kinect, because I want to redo the run of the node (because I made the changes), the kinect disconnects. When I try to restart it no longer connects and I have to restart the PC to make it work.
I use ros electric in ubuntu 11.10.
This is the message when the kinect disconnects: [camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 2623, exit code -6].

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33507/problem-with-kinect/) by [Giu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2337/giu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the information provided, I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.  However, here are a couple of tips for debugging.  First you don't need a separate `roscore`; using `roslaunch` on `openni.launch` will automatically start a core (this will just save you a step).

You very likely do not have to restart your entire computer if the `openni.launch` process does crash.  Often, I have found that reloading the udev service is enough to get the Kinect restarted.  So if `openni.launch` is failing to start the Kinect, or failing to publish any data, try unplugging the Kinect and running the command

```
sudo service udev reload
```

Then try again.

Launching the `openni.launch` with debugging turned on will allow you to get a backtrace of the error.  This could possibly lead to the cause of your problem.  Run

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch debug:=true
```

a separate xterm window running gdb will pop up.  In that window type `run`, and the node will start running.  Then if the node crashes, you can type `bt` in the gdb window to generate a backtrace of the error.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-03-12**:
Wow... I did not realize how old the question was.  Maybe @Giu still cares?

**Comment by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on 2013-03-12**:
Neither did I, I just was looking at unanswered questions.